# Simple magento cronjob extension

Tags: magento, cron

I'm trying to write a simple extension that registers a cron job for magento and there seems to be something I'm missing out here. The cron job is never scheduled there is no entry for it in cron_schedule table. I even tried entering one there and the job was never executed. The default magento cron job's are running fine. And by looking at the /var/log/syslog I can see the cron.sh being executed.
The extension is very simple. Just a model (Observer.php) and config.xml that should set up the cron job. I feel like a fool. From what I read online this should be fairly simple to set up and yet I'm getting nowhere with it.

Here is the content of config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Twobuy_Import>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </Twobuy_Import>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
            <twobuy_import>
                <class>Twobuy_Import_Model</class>
            </twobuy_import>
        </models>
    </global>
    <crontab>
        <jobs>
            <twobuy_import>
                <schedule>
                    <cron_expr>50 13 * * *</cron_expr>  <!-- I set this value to say 10-20-30 minutes in the future, and wait, nothing ever happens -->
                </schedule>
                <run>
                    <model>twobuy_import/observer::parse</model>
                </run>
            </twobuy_import>
        </jobs>
    </crontab>
</config>
```

Here is the Twobuy_Import.xml in app/etc/modules (the extension is showed under system->configuration->advanced)

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Twobuy_Import>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </Twobuy_Import>
    </modules>
</config>
```

And the Observer.php

```
class Twobuy_Import_Model_Observer
{
    public function parse()
    {
        $row = 1;
        if (($handle = fopen(Mage::getBaseDir('var')."/orders/Stock/webstock.csv", "r")) !== FALSE)
        {
            while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE)
            {
                if($row++ > 1)
                {
                    if($product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->loadByAttribute('sku',$data[1]))
                    {
                        $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product->getEntityId());
                        $product->setPrice($data['3']);
                        $product->setAnalysiscode($data['4']);
                        if($data[5] == 'Y')
                            $stockData['is_in_stock'] = 0;
                        else
                            $stockData['is_in_stock'] = 1;
                        $product->setStockData($stockData);
                        try
                        {
                            $product->save();
                        }
                        catch (Exception $e)
                        {
                           Mage::log('Saving error with the following message: '.$e->getMessage());
                           Mage::log('Saving product:');
                           Mage::log($product->getData);
                           Mage::log('CSV line:');
                           Mage::log($data);
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Mage::log('Import error, sku not found: '.$data[1]);
                        Mage::log('CSV line:');
                        Mage::log($data);
                    }
                }
            }
            fclose($handle);
        }
        else
        {
            Mage::log('Import, no csv file found!')
        }
    }
}
```

Also here is my cron job configuration from system->configuration->system:

```
Generate Schedules Every 1
Schedule Ahead for 5
Missed if Not Run Within 20
History Cleanup Every 30
Success History Lifetime 60
Failure History Lifetime 600
```

Comment: Have you configured your system such that it will run Magento's `cron.sh` file? If you're unsure what I'm talking about, please see this: www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/how_to_setup_a_cron_job

Comment: Like I said. The internal cron jobs are runnign fine and I can see cron.sh beign executed in the /var/log/syslog

Furthermore I added Mage::log('Cron Started') at the beginning of the cron.php file. Everything I see so far suggests that the cron job's are being executed. The problem is that my extensions cron job is not being registered by magento.

Comment: can you try changing the cron_expr to `*/2 * * * *`, so that it can run every 2 minutes and you can check it? don't forget to clear cache.

Comment: I've set it to every two minutes. No luck still. I tried that before.
Also the cron.sh is executed every minute if that can help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run cron like this so you get an error log to read:

```
* * * * * /usr/bin/php /home/magento/public_html/cron.php >> /home/magento/public_html/var/log/cron.log 2>&1
```

Also pop this extension on: http://connect20.magentocommerce.com/community/Aoe_Scheduler it will let you run cron jobs whenever you want, clear the schedule and rebuild it.

No I cannot tell you why your extension is not working, however, with logging and control over your extension you should be on easy street.

You may also want this:

config.xml:

```
<events>
  <mymodule_update_stuff>
    <observers>
      <mymodule_update_stuff_handler>
        <type>model</type>
        <class>mymodule/observer</class>
        <method>updateStuff</method>
        <args/>
      </mymodule_update_stuff_handler>
    </observers>
  </mymodule_update_stuff>
</events>
....
<crontab>
<jobs>
  <mymodule_updatestuff>
    <schedule>
      <!--<cron_expr>*/15 * * * *</cron_expr> -->
      <config_path>mymodule/misc/frequency</config_path>
    </schedule>
    <run>
      <model>mymodule/observer::updateStuff</model>
    </run>
  </mymodule_updatestuff>
</jobs>
</crontab>
```

Now in system.xml:

```
<config>
<sections>
<mymodule translate="label" module="mymodule">
  <label>Whatever</label>
  <tab>catalog</tab>
  <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
  <sort_order>200</sort_order>
  <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
  <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
  <show_in_store>0</show_in_store>
  <groups>
    <misc translate="label">
      <label>Import Options</label>
      <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
      <sort_order>0</sort_order>
      <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
      <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
      <show_in_store>0</show_in_store>
      <fields>
        <frequency translate="label">
          <label>Update Frequency</label>
          <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
          <sort_order>100</sort_order>
          <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
          <show_in_website>0</show_in_website>
          <show_in_store>0</show_in_store>
        </frequency>
```

You will now be able to put your cron schedule in the admin config for your module rather than have it hard wired into your config.xml. This makes it easier to develop a cron-style module.

Comment: Well the problem was in naming of the folder that held the extension :(

it was TwoBuy instead of Twobuy... and yes I'am an idiot. The extension registers a cron job now. Thanks for sharing your knowledge on how to debug magento crons even though it did not help me find anything I did not know already in this case. I'm sure it will help me alot in the future.

Comment: As a developer starting with magento, can you elaborate what the config between the `<events></events>` tag does? As I understand you are registering an event listener but I'm not sure why?